# Ошибка при обнолении

Tags: android, android-studio

При обновлении появилась такая проблема: Сначала все загружается но на моменте "Patching Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image 20 to 22" останавливается и дальше уже никуда не идет.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Удалите этот image и поставьте снова. Тогда патчится будет нечему и все будет Ок.

Comment: А у Вас на диске место свободное есть? Или может он старый/бракованный и даёт сбои? Потому что не должно быть проблем на ровном месте при каждом обновлении.